# Scaling Imageview on auto rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, autoscaling, screen-rotation

I am getting a url and displaying it in Imageview. the auto roation of my device is ON. i want the imageview to scale according to width of device once it is rotated.

is it possible when I am getting image from a url?

Comment: set imageview width parameter to match_parent and scaleType to fitXY

Comment: it is stretching my image

Comment: if that scale type doesnt work for you since you want to keep the aspect ratio, take a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html if that doesnt work either, you will have to do some scaling by yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in code as well if the image is adjusted in away that doesnt look right or you just want more control over what is happening on rotate.

First get the device width and height:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Then you can use that information to resize the image.

You can set `o.inJustDecodeBounds = true` to get the image sizes without loading the image. If the image is to big, you can resize it. Example code below.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

    Uri uri = getImageUri(path);
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
        in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
        in.close();

        int scale = 1;
        while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale++;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

        Bitmap b = null;
        in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

        if (scale > 1) {
            scale--;
            // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
            // larger than target
            o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inSampleSize = scale;
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

            // resize to desired dimensions
            int height = b.getHeight();
            int width = b.getWidth();
            Log.d(TAG, "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ", height: " + height);

            double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (((double) width) / height));
            double x = (y / height) * width;

            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x, (int) y, true);
            b.recycle();
            b = scaledBitmap;

            System.gc();

        } else {
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        }
        in.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "bitmap size - width: " +b.getWidth() + ", height: " + b.getHeight());
        return b;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
        return null;
    }
}
```